# HTTP2 push after serving content

Tags: http2

Is it possible to push content to the client after the requested content has already been served?

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push) explains the sequence of frames as follows:

> 1. Server receives HEADERS frame asking for index.html in stream 3...
> 2. Server sends a PUSH_PROMISE for styles.css and a PUSH_PROMISE for script.js, again in stream 3...
> 3. Server sends a HEADERS frame in stream 3 for responding to the request for index.html.
> 4. Server sends DATA frame(s) with the contents of index.html, still in stream 3.
> 5. Server sends HEADERS frame for the response to styles.css in stream 4
> 6. Server sends HEADERS frame for the response to script.js in stream 6.
> 7. Server sends DATA frames for the contents of styles.css and script.js, using their respective stream numbers.

I was wondering if, for example, I could keep open stream 3 and after I sent the DATA frame(s) for index.html and afterwards send PUSH_PROMISE frames.

Thanks for any responses :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to push content to the client after the requested content has already been served?

I believe the answer is 'no', based on *6.6. PUSH_PROMISE* in RFC 7540. Here's the relevant quote (emphasis mine):

> PUSH_PROMISE frames MUST only be sent on a peer-initiated stream
>   that    is **in either the "open" or "half-closed (remote)" state**.  The
>   stream    identifier of a PUSH_PROMISE frame indicates the stream it
>   is    associated with.  If the stream identifier field specifies the
>   value    0x0, a recipient MUST respond with a connection error
>   (Section 5.4.1)    of type PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Back to your question:

> I was wondering if, for example, I could keep open stream 3 and after I sent the DATA frame(s) for index.html and afterwards send PUSH_PROMISE frames.

Here's something that I believe you could do, along those lines: you could send all `DATA` frames for stream 3 *but withhold the `END_STREAM` flag* thus keeping the (which means that the client would still be waiting for content). Then send the `PUSH_PROMISE`, then send an empty (zero length) `DATA` frame with `END_STREAM` set on stream 3. I can't think of a scenario where that would be useful, however.

Comment: Most browsers allow pushed content to be used for other streams in a connection, but they only use pushed content once. See "If the connection closes, bye bye push cache" and "Items in the push cache can only be used once" https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/  The race condition is that the client will parse html and request css/js before realizing it's on the way. The only possible scenario where this seems useful is if you wanted to **increase the likelihood** that promised content be used later.